# NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/cache/CachePlugin

Tags: java, playframework, redis

Play Framework version is 2.4.6. When loading webpage I have error NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/cache/CachePlugin. I changed scala version from 2.10.5 to 2.11.6.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/cache/CachePlugin
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
 java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
 play.utils.Reflect$.getClass(Reflect.scala:142)
 play.api.Plugins$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Plugins.scala:88)
 play.api.Plugins$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Plugins.scala:87)
 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
 scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
 scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
 play.api.Plugins$.loadPlugins(Plugins.scala:87)
 play.api.Plugins$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Plugins.scala:100)
 play.api.Plugins$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Plugins.scala:100)
 play.api.Plugins.thePlugins$lzycompute(Plugins.scala:59)
 play.api.Plugins.thePlugins(Plugins.scala:59)
 play.api.Plugins.length(Plugins.scala:60)
 scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$class.iterator(IndexedSeqLike.scala:90)
 play.api.Plugins.iterator(Plugins.scala:57)
 scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
 play.api.Plugins.foreach(Plugins.scala:57)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:92)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87)
 play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
 play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:156)
 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
 scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
 scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)
 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1423)
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:902)
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1644)
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

** application.conf **

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Cache
play.modules.disabled+="play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"
play.cache.redis.bindCaches = ["db-cache", "user-cache", "session-cache"]

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
play.crypto.secret="</N_v`W4xv8GY^c7e=UCDYF]vXSguUvABIHoi[JNm1j@lf2C6S9TL[?FNM?ImDd;"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
# global=Global

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"

#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
# db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
evolutions=disabled

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
ebean.default = "models.*"

#ebean.order = ["models.Order", "models.OrderItem"]

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/), by providing a logger.xml file in the conf directory .

# Root logger:

play.i18n.langs=["fr","en"]

# The public facing name of the site.  Used when sending reset emails.
server.hostname="localhost:9000"

include "mail"

# Redis
redis.cache=enabled
redis.uri="redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

** build.sbt **

```
import sbt.Keys._

name := """app"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  "com.typesafe.play"         %% "play"                   % "2.4.0"     % "provided",
  "com.typesafe.play"         %% "play-cache"             % "2.4.0",
  "org.mindrot"               % "jbcrypt"                 % "0.3m",
  "com.typesafe.play"         %% "play-mailer"            % "3.0.1",
  "org.sedis"                 %% "sedis"                  % "1.2.2",
  "com.typesafe.play.modules" %% "play-modules-redis"     % "2.4.0",
  filters
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Apache"                  at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
    "jBCrypt Repository"      at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/"
)

resolvers += "sedis-fix" at "https://dl.bintray.com/graingert/maven/"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava, PlayEbean)

fork in run := true
```

Comment: add the 'cache' dependency in your build.sbt file??

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/cache/CachePlugin too